# HTML text color of my button isn't coming out correctly

Tags: html, css

I'm a n00b, so go easy on me. :)

Right now I'm stuck because I need to figure out why the text color of the two named buttons (**Resume** and **Programs**) isn't white. The buttons reside inside divs of class `outerdiv`; thus they should inherit the property `font-color: #FFFFFF`. But apparently they aren't doing that, since the font is still black.

Please explain the HTML logic that corrects this problem.

Code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>my site</title>


    <style type="text/css">
        p
        {
            font-family: Arial;
            color: #FFFFFF;
        }
        #mtx_bckgd
        {
            font-family: "Courier New";
            height: 750px;
            width: 1000px;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: -1;
            background: linear-gradient(180deg, #39275b, #FFFFFF);
        }
        #mtx_bckgd > p
        {
            word-wrap: break-word;
            color: #D8D8D8;     
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        #headerbox
        {
            height: 50px;
            top: 25px;
            left: 5px;
        }
        h1
        {
            color: #FFFFFF;
            font-weight: 400;
            text-align: center;
            margin: auto;
            padding: auto;
            text-shadow: 2px 2px rgb(51,51,51);

        }
        #navbar
        {
            top: 120px;
            left: 5px;
            width: 1000px;
            height: 30px;
        }
        #uwlogo
        {
            height: 50px;
            float: left;
        }
        #JaminWEB
        {
            margin: 0px auto;
        }
        .navbutton
        {
            width: 33%;
            height: 25px;
            background-color: rgba(51,51,51,0.5);
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }
        #footer
        {
            top: 800px;
        }
        .outerdiv
        {
            position: absolute;
            font-family: Arial;
            width: 1000px;
            border: solid 2px #FFFFFF;
            background-color: rgba(215,169,0,0.5);
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            font-color: #FFFFFF;
        }

    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function change_bckgd()
        {
            var bitstr = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < 4000; ++i)
                bitstr += Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) % 2 ? "0" : "1";
            document.getElementById("mtx_txt").innerHTML = bitstr;

        }

    </script>


</head>
<body>
    <div id="mtx_bckgd">
        <p id="mtx_txt"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="outerdiv" id="headerbox">
        <div id="uwlogo">
            <img src="C:\Users\XXXXXX\Desktop\uwlogo.png" height="50px">
        </div>
        <div id="JaminWEB">
            <h1>JaminWEB</h1>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="outerdiv" id="navbar">
        <input type="button" class="navbutton" value="Resume"/>
        <input type="button" class="navbutton" value="Programs"/>
        <input type="button" class="navbutton"/>



    <div class="outerdiv" id="footer">
        <p>Last modified: March 21st, 2014</p>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        setInterval(change_bckgd, 200);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in your `.outer-div` rules, you have `font-color` which isn't a property, it's just `color`. But if you correct that, you'll see the text is still black, the default color. That's because browsers are notorious for having issues when rendering form controls.

As the [MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Styling_HTML_forms#Fonts_and_text):

> CSS font and text features can be used easily with any widget (and
>   yes, you can use @font-face with form widgets). However, browsers'
>   behaviors are often inconsistent. By default, some widgets do not
>   inherit font-family and font-size from their parents. And many
>   browsers use the system default appearance instead.

The  easiest way to fix this would be to add `color:inherit;` or `color:white` to your `.navbutton` class

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/zYNL8/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
.outerdiv input[type=button]
        {
           color:#fff;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `.navbutton` to have a color of white in the css, or adding `color:inherit` should work. And the proper "font-color" property in CSS is just "color", fyi.

Example:

```
.navbutton
    {
        width: 33%;
        height: 25px;
        background-color: rgba(51,51,51,0.5);
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        color: #fff;
    }
```

**Inputs don't automatically inherit all parent styles, so you have to specify to inherit, or specify the style you want.**